# Combining button_to with a path helper and a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hate having to ask this but I've tried every combination and again I am tripped up by `rails magic` ?

```rb
<%= button_to ( "Edit this question" , options: {edit_question_path(@question)} , class: "btn btn-secondary") %>
```

(this is just one of 100 variations that I've tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the correct syntax...

```rb
button_to 'Edit this question', edit_question_path(@question), class: 'btn btn-secondary'
```

More in the docs on [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)